# how to remove the " quote from string?

Tags: ruby, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby code for modifying outer quotes on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424384/ruby-code-for-modifying-outer-quotes-on-strings)

This is my string:

```
msgid """We couldn't set up that account, sorry.  Please try again, or contact an ""admin (link is above)."
```

I want to remove all the double quotes except the first and last one.
How may I do that?

Comment: Why are there quotation marks in the string to start off with?

Comment: It looks like a mangled Python triple-quoted string literal.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424384/ruby-code-for-modifying-outer-quotes-on-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming your strings will always be of the "msgid..." format shown above and your inteded output was 'msgid "text here"':

```
>> str.gsub(/(msgid )"{1,}(.*) "{1,}(.*)"/, '\1"\2 \3"')
=> "msgid "We couldn't set up that account, sorry.  Please try again or contact an admin (link is above).""
>> puts str.gsub(/(msgid )"{1,}(.*) "{1,}(.*)"/, '\1"\2 \3"')
msgid "We couldn't set up that account, sorry.  Please try again or contact an admin (link is above)."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option as long as you know you always want a quote at the beginning and at the end.

Assume x is holding the sting you want to manipulate.

```
x = '"' + x.gsub('"', '') + '"'
```

Comment: The way I understood the question, he wanted `msgid "...."`, not `"msgid ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
msg = %q{msgid """We couldn't set up that account, sorry.  Please try again, or contact an ""admin (link is above)."}
print 'msgid "' << msg.sub('msgid ', '').gsub('"', '') << '"'
# >> msgid "We couldn't set up that account, sorry.  Please try again, or contact an admin (link is above)."
```

If "msgid" precedes every line, then remove it, deal with the double-quotes by stripping them, then put back "msgid" and add the desired leading and trailing double-quotes again.

Answer (score 0):

msgid is actuall 3 strings because of the strings delimiters of double quotation marks. So you could just:

```
msgid = ""<<"We couldn't set up that account, sorry. Please try again, or contact an "<<"admin (link is above)."
```

Or if you want to take a long route:

```
x = %q{}
  msgid = """We couldn't set up that account, sorry. Please try again, or contact an ""admin (link is above)."
  x << msgid
  x.gsub!('"', '')
  msgid = ""
  msgid << x
# Check
  puts x
```